# What happen when multiple apps use the GPS on iOS?

Tags: ios, gps, location, cllocationmanager

On iOS we are using the GPS to track users.

We had a strange case last week where a user were moving quite good, and then suddenly one point from the GPS could be totally off (~500 meters), and then moved again and then suddenly a totally off point again (again about 500 meters).

We are using filter and have set the accuracy to only get good GPS-points, and these kind of bad GPS-coordinates is nothing we normally see.

Because of this behaviour I started to think about how the GPS works in iOS when multiple apps are using the GPS at the same time.

We require a good accuracy, We use `kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation` or `kCLLocationAccuracyBest`. They should only use the GPS and not any wifi/cellular or similar. We also filter out anything with an accuracy (fault tolerance) higher than 130.

But what happen if another app is also using the GPS with the settings of `kCLLocationAccuracyThreeKilometers`. Could it be that our app receives those updates and therefore we get bad accuracy because of that?

Comment: We also see that for the coordinates that are wrong we can see that we get a good horisontal accuracy reported but the altitude reported from the GPS is a larege negative number (such as -157), where a normal altitude in that area is positive around 5-10.

Comment: We don't have any problems with battery drain or app rejects. The question is about when two apps are using the GPS, and we control one of the apps, and another company controls the other).

Comment: iOS will use the most accurate setting that is requested, so in your example the GPS receiver will be used as your app is asking for "best". If your app terminated then the GPS may be turned off if the other app only wants 3k or significant location changes. What was the physical environment where you had the problem?  Tall buildings in a city or even a bridge or tunnel can cause sudden shifts in location.